# Specify the git branch for bower registry

Tags: git, bower, bower-register

I want to specify a branch name while doing bower register instead of bower defaulting the git branch to **master**.

> bower register mypackage git@gitlab.example.com:mypackage.git#**branch**

but the above command doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [looking at the source code](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/lib/commands/register.js) it seems like Bower simply does not support that (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Just to update (since I cannot currently comment on the accepted answer), I think it works as you described now -- something like this would be in your bower.json files dependency section:

```
"name-of-dependency": "git+ssh://git@git.<org name here>.com/path/to/gitfile.git"
```